# Emacs Regex - shortkey

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp

i have no clue about lisp...
i have a small feature that i would like to have, if someone can help me it will be great.

when i want to do regex i do C-M-s and enter my text,
most of the time i'm searching for whole word so i do something like this

C-M-s \[^*] (The ^* is to match exact word without _)

i would like to have bindkey/function that i press the key,
its open text box search i enter my text and its auto add \< at the begin
and > at the end

can you please assist?

Thanks Jony

Answer (score 1):

Your description is not clear (to me), but it sounds like you just want to do incremental word search.

In that case, just do it: `M-s w`.  See the Emacs manual, node [Word Search](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Word-Search.html).